# Grouping TabPages in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I group TabPages in the TabControl: the first group - on the first line, the second group - on the second line.

Image for example:
[image]

Comment: I would, and always did, go for nested tab controls

Comment: tabs are automatically wrapped when width is not enough. TabControl's `UseLayoutRounding` property must be set to False

Comment: @JesseJames: I cannot found that property... is it by chance in WPF's TabControl ? We're talking of winforms here...

Comment: @slawekwin: "nested tab controls" is the answer to the question alright, BUT it's very bad UI design... Instead go for some sort of treeview as a sidebar

Answer (score 2):

Set TabControl's Multiline property to true

[image]

Comment: Multiline property shows the tabs on multiple lines when the horizontal space finishes. The OP wants to show *always* tabs on different lines...